# yii2 dectrium rbac rule validation class does not exist

Tags: yii2, rbac

I'm using dectrium rbac. I created the following rule:

```
<?php
namespace common\rbac;
use yii\rbac\Rule;
class OwnerRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'isOwner';

    public function execute($user, $items, $params) {
        if (!isset($params['object'])) return false;
        if (!isset($params['object']->author_id)) return false;
        return $params['object']->author_id == $user;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to create the rule in the backend, dectrium rbac provides. Doing this I get the error message "Class OwnerRule does not exist". Obviously

```
if (!class_exists($this->class))
```

returns true. What might be the reason?

Comment: Have you registered the Rule in the database?

Comment: Yes I did register it. But after reading your post I realized that I had to write the full qualified name into the field, "common\rbac\OwnerRule" instead of only the class name.